# Hydrogen atom orbital projections resemble to some Chladni figures! Mathematical reasoning?

Tags: orbitals, hydrogen

Chladni figures are formed by sprinkling salt on a vertically vibrating membrane, f.e. [image: 1]. Some of them are purported to be projections of hydrogen atom orbitals f.e. 1s, 2s, 2p, 3d, e.t.c., f.e. [image: 3]

One could bring it down to that the vibration patterns of Chladni figures are, as known, two-dimensional standing waves (this part is well established) and also to that -according to the Copenhagen (Born) interpretation- the hydrogen electron distribution also follows a (three-dimensional) standing wave pattern.

So far, so good, but what about the mathematical reasoning lying behind?

Could we claim that the two-dimensional Schrodinger equation for the hydrogen atom (i.e. the radial associated Laguerre polynomial, Ln) and the Chladni figures equation (i.e. the Bessel function of the first kind, Ja) are linear to each other?  Any thoughts on the mathematical reasoning would be highly welcome..

Comment: It would be helpful to cite a source for the resemblance and show some examples of ones that actually match orbitals.

Comment: Indeed. Examples added.

Comment: Modes of a 2D membrane and modes of 3D spherical harmonics will have a number of similarities just because of symmetry requirements. That is all.

Comment: Also suitable for Mathematics if you are looking for mathematical "finesse".And I would say what are the mathematical similarities or something like that. There shouldn't be any real reasoning, perhaps just reasons.

Comment: I was hoping -rather in a naive way- to find some linear relation between associated Laguerre polynomial (L) and Bessel function of first kind (J)-the main part of the Chladni figure equation. I have found a number of relations between but none which shows a straightforward relation, at least in my eyes..